# Rails "is not a module" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I built a library on "lib" rails directory. The structure of library is something like this:

```
 lib/insurance/broker/fake_broker.rb
```

the class looks like the following example:

```
module Insurance
  module Broker
    class FakeBroker
      def initialize(user_id, user_secret)
        @user_id = user_id
        @user_secret = user_secret
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, in my result_controller I'm doing this:

```
require 'insurance/broker/fake_broker'

 def show
   broker = Insurance::Broker::FakeBroker.new(1234,1234)
 end
```

but Rails is returning this error:

```
Insurance is not a module
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: `fake_broker.rb` is likely not included in your Rails load path

Comment: But I'm including with require 'insurance/broker/fake_broker'

Comment: Try `require Rails.root.join('insurance', 'broker', 'fake_broker')` to see if it changes anything. Also, when calling new, you'll need two arguments I believe according to your initialize method (this is another forecasted problem ;) )

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Ruby is telling you that it found an `Insurance`, but it is not a module.
Perhaps you already have defined an `Insurance` **class**?

Depending on the surrounding code it might help if you "reset" the namespace by prepending a double colon:

```
broker = ::Insurance::Broker::FakeBroker.new(1234,1234)
```

Comment: Sounds logical ... maybe you have a Rails Model called Insurance too?

Comment: In that case the double colon won't help because the model would be at the top level, too.

Comment: Yeaappp. That was the problem! I have a model Insurance. Thanks man!

Comment: Thank you! I don't have any model's named "Monitor" in my case - But renaming it did the trick! Must be a reserved word or something.

Comment: There is a Ruby internal class named `Monitor`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/monitor/rdoc/Monitor.html

Comment: I was trying to define a module using a name in the same scope that was already being used to create a class. This answer was very helpful for me to realize that!

Comment: Are you not allowed to create both a class and a module with the same name at the same level?

Comment: @Jwan622 That's correct, because class and module names are constants which reference the class/module. Even if you redefine the constant you'll lose the original value.

Comment: ah that last sentence made sense to me... you're redefining the constant to point to something different. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities can be for such error that in directory level, a class also exists with the same name, therefore it will be referring to that class. Please check the directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).